# Parse just unit with pint

Tags: python, pint

The pint docs are clear about [how to parse a quantity](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#string-parsing) like "1 meter". How do I parse just a unit, like "meter"? All of these return a quantity with a value of 1:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

ureg('meter')  # Quantity 1 meter
ureg['meter']  # Quantity 1 meter
ureg.parse_expression('meter')  # Quantity 1 meter
```

I know that I can do `quantity.u` or `quantity.units` to get just the units, but that seems clunky.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a use-case, concretely: What's the purpose and reason behind your requirement to __parse just a unit__ (without quantity) ? What are your inputs (from), when parsing?

Answer (score 4):

Each registry has a `Unit` class that can be used to parse a string directly into a unit:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

ureg.Unit('m')  # Unit meter
```